# Populating database with faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker

I want to populate the database with a number of stores and users, that each user corresponds to one store. The issue with the code below is that I get the error **Validation failed: Email has already been taken.**

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    make_stores
    make_users
  end
end

def make_stores
  50.times do 
    name = Faker::Company.name
    manager = Faker::Name.name
    address = Faker::Address.street_name
    Store.create!(name: name,
                  manager: manager,
                  address: address)
  end
end

def make_users
  stores = Store.all(limit: 8)

  99.times do |n|
    first_name  = Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
    email = "example-#{n+1}@example.org" 
    password  = "password"
    stores.each { |store| store.users.create!(first_name: first_name,
                  last_name: last_name,
                 email:    email,
                 password: password,
                 password_confirmation: password) }
  end
end
```

Comment: You got that error the first time you ran the code, or subsequent times?

Comment: no I rake db:reset the first time i got the error, but then when I populate it I got the same error

Comment: Delete all users and retry it.

Comment: @SoniKishan I did by reseting the database. The issue seems to be that the loop is not working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the email variable before calling `stores.each`, so all 8 stores will get a user with the same email.

Do something like this instead:

```
def make_users
  stores = Store.all(limit: 8)

  99.times do |n|
    password  = "password"
    stores.each do |store|
      first_name  = Faker::Name.first_name
      last_name = Faker::Name.last_name
      email = "#{store.name.parameterize}-#{n+1}@example.org" 
      store.users.create!(first_name: first_name,
                  last_name: last_name,
                  email:    email,
                  password: password,
                  password_confirmation: password)
    end
  end
end
```

Now the first 8 users will have an email like `(some-store-name)-1@example.org`, next 8 will have `(some-store-name)-2@example.org` and so on.

Comment: May the Gods of Asgard be with you my friend.

Comment: May Odin protect you in battle.